# Ubuntu 14.10 NFS share does not work

Tags: mount, fstab, nfs, 14.10

I have an NFS share on my QNAP NAS. I can connect to this share from multiple desktops & laptops with Ubuntu (and Fedora).

The thing is that it won't work with Ubuntu 14.10. Am I doing something wrong, is it a bug or do I need to configure it somehow different with 14.10?

What I normally do is this:

```
sudo apt-get install nfs-common
sudo mkdir /mnt/qnap
sudo chown -R jos:jos /mnt/qnap
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`
```

and then I add the following line to /etc/fstab:

"the ipadress for my qnap":/Multimedia /mnt/qnap nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr

Comment: This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1385846

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do

sudo vi /etc/rc.local

add this line:

mount -a

save file and reboot

NOTE: 14.10 is using an implementation of systemd to enable/start all its services... I don't think its working quite right yet. The NFS mount is failing because networking has not yet started during boot. Adding "mount -a" to your /etc/rc.local file is a work-around that I'm currently using with success.